# Import from CSV file to SQL Error

Tags: sql, sql-server, csv

I have a CSV file with following columns

```
ID                    State                     Email
1020202034566949       LA                     r1@abc.com
1020202034543245       CA                     r2@abc.com
1020202034521234       TX                     r3@abc.com
1020202034521345       TN                     r4@abc.com
1020202034589789       NY                     r5@abc.com
```

But wen I import them to sql table I get following result

```
     ID                         State                     Email
    1.020202034566949E+15        LA                     r1@abc.com
    1.020202034543245E+15        CA                     r2@abc.com
    1.020202034521234E+15        TX                     r3@abc.com
    1.020202034521345E+15        TN                     r4@abc.com
    1.020202034589789E+15        NY                     r5@abc.com
```

as the column is ID I need it to be exactly same like what I get,

I tried changing the format in Excel with various formats as number without decimals, special category and all but are of no use.

Comment: How does your SQL structure looks like?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pre format the cell in excel to "number", set decimal place to 0, currently it will be set at general but this struggles with larger numbers such as yours.

Had the same issue myself earlier.

**EDIT**

As commented below you will obviously need to account for such a large number in SQL server **bigint** will be enough.

**EDIT 2**
Think the only way for you to go would be to set this as a text field, I've just tested and it doesn't actually alter the number this way.

The issue is that excel will only allow accurate numbers of up to 15 charactors.

The workaround here being you have it as a text field in excel, then cast this as a big int during the import.

[image]

Comment: Also, the values in the ID column are far too large for the `int` database type, the destination column will need to be `bigint`.

Comment: It must work. What datatype is your destination column in SQL server?

Comment: datatype in sql is bigint